# How can I access web user controls within a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has three separate web user controls in each row.  Each user control contains its own grid view.  I need to be able to rebind the gridviews within the usercontrols when I rebind the parent gridview.  As I have it now, when I rebind the parent grid all of the grids within the user controls loose all of their data.  How can I access the user controls within the parent grid in order to rebind their grids when I rebind the parent grid?

Answer (score 0):

Using your parent grid's `RowDataBound` event, you could do something like this:

```
void theParentGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        DataRow row = ((System.Data.DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        MyCustomControl custControl1 = e.Row.FindControl("MyCustomControl1Id") as MyCustomControl;
        MyCustomControl custControl2 = e.Row.FindControl("MyCustomControl2Id") as MyCustomControl;
        MyCustomControl custControl3 = e.Row.FindControl("MyCustomControl3Id") as MyCustomControl;
        if (custControl1!=null)
             custControl1.bindForRow(row);
        if (custControl2!=null)
             custControl2.bindForRow(row);
        if (custControl3!=null)
             custControl3.bindForRow(row);

     }
}
```

Of course, your custom control's binding routine would handle calling the DataBind on its own grids based on the information provided by `row`.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this will only work for custom user controls.  I am using web user controls.  How would I access those?

Comment: It'll work with a web user control.  This is essentially what I do in my own apps with great success.  Just expose a public method that can be called similarly to what I've done in the example.  Your web user control will call the databind() of its grids.